# How can I limit the rows returned in a table field?

Tags: templating, field, globals

I want to limit the rows returned here to 4, then if loop.index is 3 display a separator and then output the last row.

Does the table field have that kind of control?

```
{% for row in registration.registrationCost %}
    <li class="circle">
        <h3 class="registration-cost">{{ row.cost }}</h3>
        <hr/>
        <h5>Through</h5>
        <h4>{{ row.date }}</h4>
    </li>          
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the Craft docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/table-fields) , the table field returns an array of rows.

Assuming that is the case, you should be able to use [the Twig `slice` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html):

```
{% for row in registration.registrationCost | slice(0, 3) %}
```

You can then use a simple conditional to output the row divider:

```
{% if loop.index == 3 %}  
    <hr>  
{% endif %}
```

Stephen

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Steve Abraham just suggested the same thing. I was incorrectly using .limit() before.

Comment: STEVE ALL THE THINGS!

Comment: tis a fine name -- even with your funny spelling :)

Comment: Had to comment, just to complete the set.